# Undoing `zipfile.ZipFile(****, 'w')`

Tags: python-zipfile

I was making a program and whenever I debug it, I needed to package it into a zip file. I was too lazy to compress it many times so I made a program to compress everything into a single zip file, but when I finished it, I didn't test it and didn't notice the mistake that I made which broke all files in my drive.

Then I mistakenly ran it breaking all files, and I couldn't see the pattern which stopped me from finding the solution to undo my mistake. I need the solution fast, my codes are all broken, and my projects are broken so I can't do anything. **I don't care about which language I just need the solution.**

The code that broke every single file:

```
import zipfile
import os
import glob

for file in glob.glob("**/*.*", recursive=True):
        print(file)
        with open(file, 'rb') as f:
            data = f.read()
        with zipfile.ZipFile(file, 'w') as zip_file:
            zip_file.writestr(file, data)
```

Comment: By everything... you mean everything? Even things in your `/bin`? If those things are broken, it'll be pretty hard to recover your data.

Comment: First, make a backup of all the mangled files. Then reverse the steps you applied. It looks like each zip contains a single file. Use zipfile to open an archive, pull the list of names, open the fist compressed file in the archive, read the data, write the data to the file on disk. zipfile docs are over [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipfile.html).

Answer (score 1):

Lets start by seeing what your script does.

Create a small directory tree with some files

```
mkdir x
cd x
echo abc >test1.txt
mkdir fred
echo def >fred/test2.txt
```

Now run your script in the `x` directory

```
$ python3 /tmp/p.py
test.txt
fred/file2.txt
```

As shown below, you have overwritten each file with a zipped version. Conveniently the relative paths are still present in the zip files.

```
$ unzip -l test.txt
Archive:  test.txt
  Length      Date    Time    Name
---------  ---------- -----   ----
        5  07-10-2023 10:50   test.txt
---------                     -------
        5                     1 file

$ unzip -l fred/file2.txt
Archive:  fred/file2.txt
  Length      Date    Time    Name
---------  ---------- -----   ----
        4  07-10-2023 10:50   fred/file2.txt
---------                     -------
        4                     1 file
```

**IMPORTANT** Make sure you take a copy of the zipped directory tree before running this.

To get the original files back we just need to unzip each zip file, letting it overwrite the file by adding the `-o` option in the `unzip` commandline

```
$ for x in `find -type f`; do unzip -o $x; done
Archive:  ./test.txt
 extracting: test.txt                
Archive:  ./fred/file2.txt
 extracting: fred/file2.txt
```

Double check that the original files are back

```
$ cat test.txt 
abcd
$ cat fred/file2.txt 
def
```